# Find the probability of having chosen at least one forged bill.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> On the table, there are eight $100 bills, three of which are forged. We
>   may take three of them. What is the probabiliy that we take at least
>   one forged bill?

Let's split the whole problem into subproblems. We could take one, two or three forged bills. There are $3 \cdot\binom{5}{2}$ sets with one forged bill, $\binom{3}{2} \cdot 5$ sets with two of them and $1$ set with three of them.

This adds up to 46.

There are $\binom{8}{3}$ = 56  possible sets of three, and so the probability is

$p(x) = \frac{23}{28}$

Is this the right solution? If so, is there an easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is finding the probability of have no forged bill. Because all chances add up to one, so $$1-P(0forged bill)=P(atleast1forged bills)$$

$$P(0forgedbills)=\frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{4}{7}\cdot \frac{3}{6}$$

$$P(atleast1forged bills) = 1 - \frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{4}{7}\cdot \frac{3}{6} = \frac{23}{28}$$

Comment: Your answer is actually negative

Comment: The probability of finding 0 forged bills should be 
$\binom{5}{3} / \binom{8}{3}$

Comment: So if you pick a bill, you put it back afterwards?

Comment: If you assume that order doesn't matter, the correct answer is what I wrote above. If the order does matter, it will be $5/8 * 4/7 * 3/6$

Comment: @Aemilius If you are sure you have the correct answer, why are you asking it here? You asked for an easier method, I think this is an easier method and it gives the same answer as yours.